# Conexion a Mysql via SSL

Tags: java, sql, ssl

Buenas a todos. Estoy desarrollando un programa par manejar una base de datos creada en Mysql. Mi aplicación esta echa en java y para conectarme a la base de datos por el momento estaba usando el driver manager del conector de mysql de forma insegura. Ahora que ya casi tengo finalizado el programa me gustaría conectarme de forma segura a la base de datos via SSL a ser posible pero no tengo mucha idea de que código debo integrar en mi programa para poder hacer esto. Aquí dejo el fragmento de código que estoy usando para conectarme a la base de datos. 
Gracias.

```
    private void connection() {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


            // connect way #1
            //String url1 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/usuarios";
            String url1 = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;" +  
     "databaseName=name;integratedSecurity=true;"; 
            String user = "******";
            String password = "******";

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url1, user, password);
            if (connection != null) {
                System.out.println("Connected to PRIVILEGES ACCESS");
                conect = true;
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred. Maybe user/password is invalid");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

un compañero del foro ha puesto [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323953/connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-java-using-ssl-connection), esta en ingles pero se entiende bien(También puedes ayudarte del traductor).
Un resumen es que tu base de datos tiene que se compatible con SSL y tienes que tener instalado el certificado. 
[Te dejo la documentación oficial para crear la conexión segura](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/building-with-secure-connection-support.html) y [los comandos con una pequeña explicación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/building-with-secure-connection-support.html).

Comment: Hola @Manuel y bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Para evitar problemas con enlaces rotos y mejorar la legibilidad de la respuesta, sería de interés que ampliaras la respuesta con el contenido de los enlaces que referencias. Como el código de resolución de la respuesta en StackOverflow o un extracto significativo de la documentación.